# Set values of a 2D array using specific coordinates

Tags: c++, arrays

*Disclaimer: This could apply to any programming langage but I am using C++, so I'm using the C++ tag.*

I have an array of an `xyz` structure:

```
struct xyz {
    float x, y, z;
};
```

In the array I create, at first I only initialize the `x` and `y` as I know the `z` value only later in the code like this:

```
size = Width * Height;    
Cloud = new xyz[size];

// Remplissage des indices de Pixels
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    Cloud[i].x = i % Width;

    Cloud[i].y = i / Width;
}
```

};

This results in an array that looks like that:

```
x; y; z
0; 0; 0
1; 0; 0
2; 0; 0
3; 0; 0
0; 1; 0
1; 1; 0
2; 1; 0
3; 1; 0
0; 2; 0
1; 2; 0
2; 2; 0
3; 2; 0
```

So after that, I want to set a `z` value for such `x` and `y` values but I don't know how to do that in an effective way (I don't want to use a loop that goes through my whole array until I find the right `x` and `y` set).

My problem I guess is how to do the inverse math of `Cloud[i].x = i % Width` and `Cloud[i].y = i / Width` into something to do `Cloud[??].z = someValue`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To be honest I do not understand what exactly you want to achieve. Maybe you can state this more precisely?

Comment: Indexing a 1D array to use it as 2D one always is done as `array[outerIndex * innerDimenstion + innerIndex` – now you only need to decide which of width and height are inner and outer dimension...

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ah yes sorry I copy pasted that at the end of writing my question I got them mixed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is simple mathematics. If you have x and y and want to know the index to address the z-value **later**, then you may calculate "y * width + x".

So:

```
Cloud[y * Width + x].z = zValue;
```

Comment: Ah thank you I tried that at one point and couldn't make it work but I realized I might have mixed up my x y in the calculation which is why it wasn't working! Thank you!